# Unable to add someone to my circle

Tags: google-plus

My granddaughter and I both have Google accounts and I have her in my circles.  However when she tries to add me to her circles, she cannot.  I have checked her status and I have not blocked her.  What setting(s) might be creating an issue?

Comment: What error is she getting at adding time?

Comment: Is she under 18? If I recall there were some restrictions for minors. Let me see if I can track it down.